# Уже-таки/Уже таки

Tags: untagged

Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, нужно ли это словосочетание через дефис писать? Я всё время так писал и думал, что только так правильно, так как прочитал в правилах, написанных Лопатиным, что *-таки* через дефис с наречиями пишется. Однако я решил проверить узус, и я ужаснулся тому, что я увидел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь я даже не знаю, нужен ли следующий дефис таки.

*Однако после 17-го **уже-таки** я приеду, мадемуазель-с. Я **уже-таки** нашёл суперъежа.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Частицу ***-ТАКИ*** нужно употреблять **в соответствии с ее значением** в словаре, тогда она уместна:

**Большой толковый словарь**

***-ТАКИ,*** частица. **Разг. Тем не менее, всё же, однако**. Дождался-таки свободы. Успел-таки на поезд. Таки навязался в попутчики. Принёс-таки двойку! Она таки сдержала слово.

2. Сейчас эту частицу стали использовать **неоправданно часто** без учета ее значения (вероятно, это особая **стилизация речи**), но при этом пользователи **не знают правил** ее написания. (Стоит ли этому удивляться.)

**Орфографический словарь**

***-ТАКИ***, частица, пишется через дефис с предшествующим **глаголом** (вернулся-таки), **наречием** (довольно-таки, прямо-таки) и в словах ***всё-таки, так-таки***; в остальных случаях – раздельно (он таки приедет).

Также [ПАС под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=75#pp75)